# How to calculate CPU utilization of a host that VM can take before deployment based on the VM template information?

Tags: virtual-machines, cpu-usage

I am trying to figure out based on the VM template information like

NAME = vm-example 
CPU    = 2
MEMORY = 1024
DISK = [
  type     = swap,
  size     = 2048,
  readonly = "no" ]
How can I calculate the load it have on the host before deploying it to the actual machine?

Is there a formula? Or a software tool?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. heat a wall with your head until you see stars, then count them.

This is like asking "how do I find out the top speed of a car basedon the color of the seats". All you give is confoiguration for some disc and cpu set, nothing about the actual applications running.

No, there is no sensible way to deduct that information.

Comment: Hi, but if there are basic system applications running over it. no other exclusive application is installed. if it is not possible then is there any way to calculate load of vm without deploying them on the physical machine ?

Comment: No. See - how many KG can my car load? Oh, there is no other car on the road - TOTALLY irrelevant info.